# How to parse raw E-Mail with Zend Framework 2?

Tags: php, email, zend-framework2

I have e-mails to my server being piped to my Zend Framework 2 index (following MVC) and that gets sent to my controller.

```
public function incomingMailAction()
{
    $message ='';
    $stdin = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');

    while($line = fgets($stdin)) {
        $message .= $line;
    }

    fclose($stdin);

    // Parse e-mail here and store in database (including attachments)
}
```

I can handle the storing in the database part, I just don't know how to take that raw message and then turn it into something useful (To, From, ReplyTo, CC, BCC, Headers, attachments... ect).

## Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Zend\Mail\Message::fromString($rawMessage);` It will not decode MIME body though.

Comment: How do I go about decoding that? and getting the attachments?

Answer (score 1):

I attempted to parse E-Mails with ZF2 too, but I actually found a comment in the source code of the Zend Mail component that decoding the message is on the todo list and not yet implemented. There seems to be no easy way of doing this currently.

Instead, I recommend using [php-mime-mail-parser](https://github.com/php-mime-mail-parser/php-mime-mail-parser) - I ended up using that library instead. It uses the functions of the pecl extension mailparse (which you may need to install) and is suprisingly easy. Some examples which should get you started:

```
$message = new \PhpMimeMailParser\Parser();
$message->setText($rawMail); // Other functions to set a filename exists too

// All headers are retrieved in lowercase, "To" becomes "to"
// and "X-Mailer" becomes "x-mailer"
$recipient = $message->getHeader('to');
$date = $message->getHeader('date');
$xmailer = $message->getHeader('x-mailer');

// All headers can be retrieved at once as a simple array
$headers = $message->getHeaders();
$recipient = $headers['to'];

// Attachments can be retrieved all at once as "Attachment" objects
$attachments = $message->getAttachments();

foreach($attachments as $attachment) {
  $attachment_as_array = array(
    'type' => $attachment->getContentType(),
    'name' => $attachment->getFilename(),
    'content' => (string)$attachment->getContent(),
  );
}
```

Because the library uses an existing extension of PHP and seems to be very efficient in terms of memory management it is probably a better fit to parse emails than ZF will ever be - and it is also very easy to use. The only drawback for me was the additional installation of the mailparse pecl extension on every server.

Comment: This seems the best solution at the moment. Tried it using Zend1 and ended up using this approach. Excellent!

Answer (score -1):

```
public function incomingMailAction()
{
    $message ='';
    $stdin = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');

    while($line = fgets($stdin)) {
        $email .= $line;
    }     

    fclose($stdin);

    $to1 = explode ("\nTo: ", $email);
    $to2 = explode ("\n", $to1[1]);
    $to = str_replace ('>', '', str_replace('<', '', $to2[0]));
    list($toa, $tob) = explode('@', $to);
}
```

Stolen from: [PHP email Piping get 'to' field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13548859/php-email-piping-get-to-field)

Comment: I'm looking for something *like* that but with Zend 2 Framework.